# mysql min and max values in subquery

Tags: mysql

thanks in advance for the help. I'm a noob with sql and this is probably a pretty basic question, but I have been working on it for hours and can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the question posed: 
Using aggregate functions, display the employee name (first and last name concatenated) in a field named Employee Name and the hire date of the employee who has been employed the longest and the employee who was hired last.

I have tried to code this different ways to no avail. I always get one result instead of the two I know I should get. (I know I should get two results because I'm working with a very small table and can calculate the answer by looking at it - easy to make sure I'm getting the right results that way.)

Here is one way I coded it: 
[subquery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwtWf.png)

Here, I used a sub query for the min and max. I used 'and' in between because I want both results. I only get one. If I use 'or', I get too many results
I have also tried it this way:

[min/max in select statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZZ4U.png)
Here, I still get only one employee name back, but now I get both dates. The dates are the correct dates, but I need the output to look like the first query output.

Any help anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Next time please post the code directly on stackoverflow (no need for images).
As for a solution, try to write 2 separate queries (one to get the employee that worked the longesst) and another one to get the employee who got employed last. 
When you do that, use UNION to merge both results in a single query.

Comment: Thank you...worked perfectly! Also, I will make sure to post code directly next time. This was my first post! I appreciate the feedback. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
select concat(first_name,' ',last_name), hire_date
from l_employees
where hire_date = (select max(hire_date) from l_employees)
or hire_date = (select min(hire_date) from l_employees)
```

Comment: Thank you! This also worked great. I appreciate your help.